# What does the "PK¿¿¿" response means in PHP

Tags: php, ios

Hi I'm downloading a file to an app on iOS using the function readfile() on a PHP web service and I want to know if the file is downloaded correctly but I don't know how I can do that.

So what I'm trying is to do some echo to know if the file has been downloaded like this:

```
echo "before";
readfile($file);
echo "after";
```

But the response I get is this:

```
beforePK¿¿¿
```

Any one knows what does this mean or how can I know if the file is downloaded correctly?

UPDATE:
Yes it's a zip file, here are my headers

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$ticket");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: Don't include echo statements when outputting a file; set the appropriate headers for the filetype (a zip file in this case?) and see if the file can be opened successfully on the client with the appropriate software

Comment: `readfile()` does not *download*, it *outputs* file content. And in your case that seems to be a ZIP file header and binary payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to output the contents of a zip file aren't you?

`readfile($file)` works the same as `echo file_get_contents($file)`.  If you're trying to present someone a file to download, *do not add any additional output* else you risk breaking the file.

I would also recommend reading up on the [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.  That way you can explicitly tell the browser that you're sending a file, *not* an HTML page that has file-like contents.  (See the examples involving `Content-Type`)

Answer (score 0):

PHP should be setting the correct headers prior to `readfile()` - this LITERALLY reads the file out to the browser/app... but the browser/app needs to know what to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just assume that once the connection has closed that the data is done being transferred. If you want to validate that the file has been transferred fully, and without corruption you'll need to use a data structure like XML or JSON which will:

1. Delimit the data fields and cause the XML/JSON parser to throw an error if one is omitted, aka the transfer was cut off before it finished.
2. Allow you to embed more than one piece of data with the response, eg. an MD5 hash of the file that can be re-calculated client-side to verify that the data is intact.

eg:

```
$file = 'myfile.zip';

$my_data = array(
  'file' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)),
  'hash' => md5_file($file)
)

//header calls
header(...)

echo json_encode($my_data);
exit;
```